# Using more than one erlang behaviour

Tags: erlang, gen-fsm

I have an erlang gen_fsm process that talks to a remote server via tcp using erlang's built-in gen_tcp.

I would like to make this a web-socket client. Upon some investigation, I got this erlang websocket client library [Erlang Websocket client](https://github.com/jeremyong/websocket_client).

looking at some examples, it looks like I have to use the

> -behaviour(websocket_client_handler).

Basically, I do this in my start_link

```
start_link(UserID) ->
   gen_fsm:start_link(?MODULE, [UserID], []).
```

However, the other behavior expects a different return values for the init and a different state. I already have a state for my gen_fsm.

Can someone throw some context around this.

I think it is nothing wrong in having two behaviors defined for the same module but given that each behavior requires different return types in the init/[1/2] functions, I start to think if this is really something feasible. Just wanted to reach out to someone experienced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, I don't think it's a problem: `init/1` and `init/2` are two completely different functions, `gen_fsm:start_link` will only call `init/1` and `websocket_client:start_link` will only call `init/2`. And of course, the state from `gen_fsm`'s callbacks won't be passed to `websocket_client`'s, so they can be completely different. In practice, I'd expect it to be really confusing.

Instead, I'd separate the websocket client into a separate module which is called from the `gen_fsm` (if I understood you correctly).